# Tikz draw circle shell from inner to outer diameter

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any way to draw a circle from an inner to an outer diameter in a `tikzpicture` environment? I'd like to avoid using pstricks as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403349/draw-tikz-circles-with-a-specific-outer-radius/403352).

As in this MWE, but without having to draw circle/node *B* above *A* (opacity=.5 added to show the "unwanted" inner part of circle A):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    shapes.misc,    % additional shapes, such as rounded rectangles
    positioning,    % advanced positioning
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, thick, inner sep=0em, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=1, font=\small},
    ]
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm, fill=red!20] (nodeA) at (1, 0) {};
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=5mm, fill opacity=.5] (nodeB) at (1, 0) {B};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `[even odd rule]` for `\fill`.  Also, you need the radii for the nodes, which is half the minimum size.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    shapes.misc,    % additional shapes, such as rounded rectangles
    positioning,    % advanced positioning
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=white, thick, inner sep=0em, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=1, font=\small},
    ]
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm] (nodeA) at (1, 0) {};
    %\path (nodeA.north);
    %\pgfgetlastxy{\xa}{\ya}
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=5mm] (nodeB) at (1, 0) {B};
    %\path (nodeB.north);
    %\pgfgetlastxy{\xb}{\yb}
    %\fill[even odd rule, red] (1,0) circle[radius=\yb] circle[radius=\ya];
    \fill[even odd rule, red] (1,0) circle[radius=7.5mm] circle[radius=2.5mm];
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try both answers tomorrow and respond afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fill `even odd rule`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick,fill=red!20,even odd rule] (1,0) circle (7.5mm) (1,0) circle (2.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Many thanks! I'll try both answers tomorrow and respond afterwards.